# Time for which application has stayed in background

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an requirement for my app that after a certain period(25 mins) it has be logged out). Now how to calculate the time in which the application has stayed in a background?

i am trying to use the  method -`applicationDidBecomeActive` and there is default code given for this using a time stamp and getting the difference between timestamps. the problem is that this difference is kind of coming odd and i am not able to understand it. 
Simply put i am to get the difference but i am not able convert into desired minutes/seconds. I would like to match if this difference is equal to 25 minutes or not(or even seconds would do) . Any simple code snippet?

Comment: Post your code, It will tell more then your story.

Comment: The way I'd do this is by having a timer on the server side that invalidates the current user session. That way when the app is opened and you touch base with the server you will see if the session has expired.

Comment: @rckoenes:this is a default commented code given in -applicationdidResume i your appdelegate.You can see this in any random project as well(comment characters are too less to paste it here) . How to use that code snippet for certain minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a `NSDate` where you enter de background:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.backgroundedDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Then when you come back to the foreground check the time difference:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {       
    if (self.backgroundedDate) {
        BOOL isTimedout =[self.backgroundedDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= -(25 * 60);
        if (isTimedout) {
            [self.rootViewController presentLogin];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !!your solution worked fine.
Is there a way if this can be implemented for
previous_date = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

****date calculated after 10 mins
current_date = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSInteger difference = current_date - previous_date;

this returns some value in nanoseconds.How can this be converted to seconds or minutes

Comment: The `timeIntervalSince1970` return a [`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/NSTimeInterval) which is in seconds, so you you want minutes just dived by 60.

Comment: the code snippet that you have given works currctly and returns time in seconds but the one i have written above(also available in -applicationDidBecomeActive ) returns milliseconds. Even the difference of two dates returns odd values i.e 186 ,142 etc even for short periods .

Comment: Everything after the decimal separator is mili seconds, so just cast it from the `NSTimeInterval` which is a `double` to a `NSInteger` and you will loose the milliseconds. This is really basic stuff.